# Risk game with python

Tags: python, loops

i am pretty much starting to learn code so my knowledge is limited.
following scenario:
there is this "risk" game where playerA rolls a dice three times and playerB two times. now the two highest results of playerA are compared to the two of player B. if the highest result of A is greater than playerBs, player A gets a point, otherwise (<=) B gets a point. The same for the second highest result of A and B. So the total results of the points could be: 2:0, 1:1 or 0:2
Now the question:
The are obviously 6^5=7776 ways to dice and 2890 of them lead to 2:0, 2611 to 1:1 and 2275 to 0:2.
How can i show this statistic by printing out for example "There are 2890 possibilities to win 2:0" ?
I am able to show for a random dice roll who wins the game, but not for all.
I would be very thankful for some help.

```
import random

r1 = random.randint(1,6)
r2 = random.randint(1,6)
r3 = random.randint(1,6)

b1 = random.randint(1,6)
b2 = random.randint(1,6)

Points_A = 0
Points_B = 0


Dice_A = [r1,r2,r3]
Dice_B = [b1,b2]


print("results of A: ", Dice_A)
print("results of B: ", Dice_B)


A = sorted(Würfel_A) 
B = sorted(Würfel_B)


if A[2] > B[1]:
    Points_A += 1
elif A[2] == B[1]:
    Points_B +=1
else: Points_B += 1
    
if A[1] > B[0]:
    Points_A += 1
elif A[1] == B[0]:
    Points_B += 1
else: Points_B += 1

print("A has ", Points_A, "Points.")
print("B has ", Points_B, "Pionts.")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

- Create a function that casts a given number of dice and sorts the results in descending order, and returns that list. For example `cast_dice(3)` could return `[6, 4, 1]`
- Use that function to produce a result for the red player and the blue player. Then zip those two lists (the third die of the red player will not play a role) so the mutual dice can be compared. Calculate the number of dice with which red wins. Red can win with either 0, 1 or 2 dice.
- To get statistics on distribution, you could create a list with three counters: one for each possible red-score. Run the above procedure thousands of times and to populate this list of three.
- Calculate an average score from that list of three

Here is an implementation:

```
from random import randint

def cast_dice(dice_count):
    return sorted((randint(1, 6) for _ in range(dice_count)), reverse=True)

def get_stats(num_rounds):
    score_counts = [0, 0, 0]  # red can score 0, 1 or 2 per round
    for round in range(num_rounds):
        reds = cast_dice(3)
        blues = cast_dice(2)
        score = sum(int(red > blue) for red, blue in zip(reds, blues))    
        score_counts[score] += 1
    return score_counts

score_counts = get_stats(10000)
red_wins = score_counts[1] + 2 * score_counts[2]
blue_wins = score_counts[1] + 2 * score_counts[0]
avg_score = red_wins / sum(score_counts)
print("Raw score counts: ", score_counts)
print("Number of winning red dice: ", red_wins)
print("Number of winning blue dice: ", blue_wins)
print("Average score for red per round: ", avg_score)  # ~1.08...
print("Average score for blue per round: ", 2 - avg_score)  # ~0.92...
print("For every blue winning die, red has", red_wins / blue_wins, "winning dice")
```

So this sampling suggests that the *expected* outcome per round is that red wins one, and blue wins one, but that red has a tiny advantage: it will happen a bit more often that red wins two than that blue wins two.

This corresponds to the mathematical results you provided in the question.

To put it a bit differently, after 13 rounds (of 3 dice against 2), blue will have lost 2 "armies" more than red (on average).

Comment: Any feedback on this answer?